Why this command line argument does not work when an emacs server is not running?
If an emacs server is already running, the following command opens an emacs frame and switches to *scratch* buffer.
"emacsclientw" -na "runemacs" -e "(switch-to-buffer \"*scratch*\")"

But if the emacs server is not running the above command does not work.
Can one modify the command line arguments in order we have the same effect if an emacs server is not running?

Not clear what you want to do. How do you expect to evaluate something in a command line outside Emacs without using an Emacs command-line client?

@Drew I mean starting emacs server and at the same time executing a function. In my example, the function is the act of switching to the scratch buffer. I can be another function.

@NickD you are right , I used bad wording in my comments. The evaluation should be done right after the server starts from commamd line.

I completely rewrote the question focusing on the specific example.

The answer to the modified question is "No": in order for the client to be able to say anything to Emacs, the server has to be running. So if the server is not running, the client cannot start it because it cannot talk to Emacs.

The options you're looking for are --alternate-editor= and maybe also --create-frame.

When alternate editor is set to the empty string, it means "start Emacs if it isn't already running, then connect to it".

Without --create-frame, Emacs will start in the background if needed, and the expression will be evaluated, but Emacs won't be displayed if it wasn't already.


So for example, if you just want to evaluate an expression (starting Emacs if needed), you can do
emacsclient --alternate-editor= -e "(switch-to-buffer \"*scratch*\")"

..and if you also want Emacs to be displayed, add --create-frame:
emacsclient --create-frame --alternate-editor= -e "(switch-to-buffer \"*scratch*\")"

(I see you're already using --alternate-editor (as -a) to specify a separate runemacs launcher/wrapper program. runemacs sounds vaguely familiar - is that the program that comes with the Windows build of Emacs, for running GUI Emacs without opening a console? If so, then you might not need it for this - I'd assume the Emacs build for Windows knows how to make --alternate-editor= work correctly.)
(I see you're also using the --no-wait option. You might need to remove it: in my testing it caused it to behave as if --create-frame wasn't specified. In any case, I don't think you really need it when doing --eval anyway, since emacsclient will return as soon as the expression is evaluated.)

Thank you. Your solution work as expected. For my case, emacsclient --no-wait --alternate-editor= -e "(switch-to-buffer \"*scratch*\")" seems to suit better.
